# Copy the reverse of a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

#### copyRev

```
void copyRev(node *head1, node *&head2)
{

    stack<int> dat;
    node* curr = head1;
    while(curr!=NULL){
        dat.push(curr->data);
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    while(!dat.empty()){
        append(head2,dat.top());
        dat.pop();
    }

}
```

#### append

```
void append(node* &head, int data){

    if(head==NULL){
        head= new node;
        head->data = data;
        head->next = NULL;
    }
    else{

        node *curr = head;
        while((curr)->next!=NULL){
            (curr) = (curr)->next;
        }
        (curr)->next = new node;
        (curr) = (curr)->next;
        (curr)->data = data;
        (curr)->next = NULL;
    }
}
```

Well, I'm trying to clone the reverse of a linked list. I know how to reverse a list in place. But this code gives me a `Bus error(code dumped)`.

This is how I call the function in `main()`

```
node *head;

    for(int i = 0;i<9;i++){
        append(head,i*i);
    }
    node *revHead;
    printList(head);

    copyRev(head,revHead);
    printList(revHead);
```

in `append()` function, I check for `NULL` head and create a new node if it is NULL. moreover, the append function properly adds the elements to the list. The problem arose only after I called the `copyRev` procedure.

I have tried in-place reversing and it works. I need to clone the reverse of a linked list. Both Iterative and Recursive solutions are welcome. Also please point out the error in the above code.

This is my own practice problem but not a homework problem

Comment: Try showing us the `append` function.

Comment: Learn to use the markup used by the Stack exchange sites.

Comment: Thanks. Will learn that.

Comment: Have you thought of wrapping your list nodes to STL conforming iterators (e.g. using `boost::iterator`) and then just let STL algorithms do the job?

Comment: @PaulMichalik: Can you give some links on it? I'm on the way to learn all these.

Comment: @SrinathGS You can start with Boost.Iterator under http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/iterator/doc/index.html. As far as I remember, it contains a tutorial how to wrap a custom list node using `boost::iterator_facade`, which is the next thing you could look at. In general, any decent introduction to STL concepts might be of help to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not initializing your pointers:

```
node *head;
node *revHead;
```

As a result they have indeterminate values (ie they are random).

Using the values in these poitners in any way is undefined behavior. Which can be your error.

Just initialize them:

```
node*  head     = NULL;
node*  revHead  = NULL;
```

#### Recursive reverse of a linked list in place:

```
void reverse(node*& head)
{
     head = reverse(head, NULL);
}
node* reverse(node* item, node* next)
{
     if (item == NULL)
     {    return next;
     }
     node*  iter = item->next;
     item->next  = next;
     return reverse(iter, item);
}
```

Comment: @SrinathGS: Yes. But there are other things I would fix first. Your style is still very C like. C++ encourages better encapsulation. Once you have done that then the recursive solution also becomes easier.

Comment: OK. Will see how I can do that. Any links on the subject?

Answer (score 0):

at first glance you forgot to initialize the list head:

```
node *head = 0;
```

**edit** thanks to Alan: and revHead too